# Best way to save JSON orderbook data in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, json, pythonanywhere

Here is the sample of the data:

```
{'rate': 0.008999, 'stamp': {'bids': [[117090.0, 11.78362353], [117075.0, 0.28], [116918.0, 0.5],[116820.0, 32.0]], 'asks': [[117104.0, 0.55206666], [117105.0, 1.11], [117142.0, 4.99974999], [117178.0, 1.0], [117191.0, 0.0669], [117348.0, 0.01], [117369.0, 1.05]]}}
```

I want to host the logger on PythonAnywhere. I'm new to mysql. As of version 5.7.8 JSON objects were added how ever pythonanywhere uses 5.6.27.

And I get this error: 
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syn
tax to use near 'JSON)' at line 1`

So I'm thinking to store it as a string VARCHAR. However you have to specify the length, this varies for each entry. So shall I just put the length to be `65,535`?

Comment: u can use TEXT to store json data

Comment: mysql 5.7 onwards you have a native datatype to store json https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: i would actually recommend doing data cleaning etc first and then saving the order book data in correctly (ie. give each bid price and bid amount it's own integer and decimal field etc)

Answer (score 0):

Usually Json are stored as NVARCHAR in Mysql DB

Answer (score 0):

- You could try to change your VARCHAR to TEXT as the fixed max size is 2¹⁶-1 = 65535 characters.
- When you insert your string in your query wrap it into double quotes "[JSON]" as you use simple quotes in your json.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use VARCHAR to TEXT type in mysql before 5.7
2. In mysql 5.7  you have a native datatype to store json
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html